# Grease Pencil silhouette to Mesh - how can this be achieve in Blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, add-on, grease-pencil

I need some help to see how something may be possible. I don't believe this feature exists yet but I'm curious to see if anyone has ideas on how to achieve it through geometry nodes/addons/whatever means possible.

I've used the grease pencil like a paintbrush to establish the 3D silhouette of a model I'd like to create. What I'd like to do is take the bounds of the selection (the area the grease pencil has filled up) and create a mesh out of that. The best comparison I can think of is how the volume-to-mesh modifier works.

Does anyone have any ideas on how that could be accomplished? I'm open to doing whatever work is needed even up to creating my own addon.

I should note that I've tried converting the grease pencil to paths and turning them into a mesh. As you'd expect, that doesn't work and just creates a mess of lines.

I'm hoping for guidance to know where to start with this. I'm including examples of the grease pencil object I'm talking about below.

[image: GP Silhouette 1]
[image: GP Silhouette 2]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you created the shape using strokes, and the resulting shape is delimited by the borders of the outline of the strokes, which are not directly transformable into a mesh, so I think you have to use some kind of workarounds:

In my fast experiment I rendered out a Black and White image of the shape, imported it as Reference image, right click and used the "Trace Image to Grease Pencil" function, using a fill material, so to obtain a regular outline of the shape.

Then converted to mesh, filled in edit mode with a single big face, extruded to give some thickness, remeshed in sculpt mode.
Back to edit mode, I selected a face of the surface, Shift G to select coplanar faces, inverted the face selection and deleted all selected.

Back in sculpt mode I did a fast pass of the smooth brush to mimic an "Antialias".

Don't know if this procedure can fit your needs.

[image]